# ping script - host down vs host not on network

Tags: shell, ping

I have the following script where I am trying to differentiate between a server that is down and a server that is no longer on the network.
If I use the ping command on the command line on a server that is just down and echo the $? I get a 1 as expected.
If I use the ping command on the command line on a server that is no longer on the network and echo the `$?` I get a 2 as expected.  I can't seem to capture this behavior in my script. On the script below, the server that is no longer on the network does not appear at all in the `badhosts` output file.  I am using the dev null on the ping line as I don't want to get the host unknown lines on the output which will skew the results.

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Take a list of hostnames and ping them; write any failures
#set -x

for x in `cat hosts`
do
ping -q -c 1 $x > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

if [ "$?" -eq 1 ];then
        echo $x is on network but down >> badhosts
elif [ "$?" -eq 2 ];then
        echo $x is not on the network >> badhosts
  fi
done
```

Comment: Your two tests use completely different syntax?

Comment: I was trying single brackets in both places and then double brackets in both places and getting same result.  Just forgot to make them match for purposes of posting here. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my script as follows and this works.

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Take a list of hostnames and ping them; write any failures
set -x

for x in `cat hosts`
do
ping -c 1 $x > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
pingerr=$?

if [ $pingerr -eq 1 ]; then
        echo $x is on network but down >> badhosts
fi

if [ $pingerr -eq 2 ]; then
        echo $x is not on the network >> badhosts
fi
done
```